# Fail to execute sonar PMD

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

We are using sonar 4.5.1 and sonar-pmd-plugin is 2.3. From last few days , I am facing issue of "too many open files " Fail to execute PMD. Following file is ignored. I found that issue is fixed in 2.4 but we cannot upgrade the plugin as it would also need upgrade to Sonar 4.5.2 version. Is there any fix or workaround for the issue ? Kindly help. We use Jenkins 1.580, Sonar 4.5.1,Maven 3.0.4.

Comment: 4.5.2 is a bug fix version, only recommended course of action would be to upgrade your SonarQube version to LTS version : 4.5.7 at time of writing and as such upgrade your PMD plugin to get the fix. Every other solution is just workaround that won't pay in the long run.

Comment: Still for now as the upgrade is not possible, what is the workaround you can suggest ? Please tell.

Comment: I don't have any. Upgrading is the only correct course of action.